# Reg : Data Conversion from EBCDIC to UTF - 8

Tags: xml, encoding, db2, ibm-mq, mainframe

I have generated an XML data by using the function **XML GENERATE**, then I placed the same data in WebSphere MQ by using an COBOL - MQPUT Batch program.

From other COBOL - MQGET batch program, I retrieved the XML data from the MQ, and I tried to insert the same data in to the pureXML table, but I was facing an error code **00002039Q**.

Because the pureXML table supports only, UTF - 8 encoding format. But our generated XML data is in EBCDIC format.

Kindly help me how to convert an EBCDIC/UTF - 16 data to UTF - 8 data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/tasks/tpxgn01.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You, for your responses.

I tried in a different way, that I generated the XML Document by specifying the the Code page conversion 1208, by using the **WITH ENCODING 1208** function, then the issue got resolved.

With that encoding format I was successfully able to insert my data in to the pureXML table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get message option MQGMO_CONVERT to request the data to be converted to a given CCSID when getting from the queue.

You can find a sample here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032130_.htm#q032130___ccode

Or in the file: amqsget0.c in the samples attached to the MQ installation.

Comment: The link is for Linux/Unix/Windows, not z/OS, so you're answering a different question (although it is possible the answer would be the same, or very similar, I don't know).

Comment: I would argue against `CONVERT` option. It is expected that the XML parser decode the character stream, provided the XML is properly encoded and/or contains the right encoding in the `<?xml` preamble.
Here is the IBM doc about PureXML encoding http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.xml/src/tpc/db2z_xmldataencoding.dita

Comment: You are right the mentioned samples aren't for mainframe, however MQGMO_CONVERT should be available the same. But I think specifying the correct encoding in the XML declaration is a nicer solution. Don't really get why you are not submitting that as an answer Stavr00.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, there should not be any explicit conversion on an XML stream. An XML document is capable of self-defining its encoding.  Sending a raw XML (no preamble) in any other encoding than UTF-8 or UTF-16 is not standard. See [Autodetection of Character Encodings](http://w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing) for discussion on encoding XML.

You should add an the preamble to your XML GENERATE data. Find the encoding consistent with your platform here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.xml/src/tpc/db2z_xmldataencoding.dita

E.g. to set the encoding to `EBCDIC/Lat1` you would prepend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM1047"?>
```

Comment: While true in concept, I find that XML parsers quite often struggle to handle  anything other than UTF-8 or ISO-8859 encoding. Of course IBM's z/OS parsers are okay at this since the mainframe is still mostly EBCDIC, but sending an XML document to some arbitrary system with 'encoding=IBM1047' is likely to be problematic.